# Find the probability density function of Z=X+Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose X,Y are independent random variables with probability density functions (pdf) $$_fX(t) = f_Y(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|t|}$$ Find the pdf $f_Z(t)$ of $Z = X + Y$.

Hint: Consider the cases $t<0$ and $t\ge 0$ separately
I'm confused because $fX$ and $fY$ are both in terms of t, so I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 2):

$$F_Z(z) = P(X+Y \leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right]dx$$

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{d}{dz}F_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right]dx$$

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,z-x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(z-x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$p\{Z\leq z\}=p\{X+Y\leq z \}=p\{X\leq z-y\mid Y=y\}=\frac{p\{X\leq z-y,Y=y\}}{p\{Y=y\}}.$$

Use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent to conclude.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that P(Z<=z)=P(X<=x)? Which isn't always true for Z=X+Y with X,Y independent.

Comment: No, that $p\{Z\leq z\}=p\{X\leq z-y\}$.