# Find the probability density function for Z = X + Y with finite ranges

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I was asked to find the probability density function of $Z = X + Y$ (given $X$ and $Y$ independent). The pdfs of $X$ and $Y$ are uniform and given as $f_x(x) = 1/a, 0 ≤ x ≤ a$ and $f_y(y) = 1/b, 0 ≤ y ≤ b$.

My background in statistics is weak, and this came out of a course only tangentially related to statistics. So after refreshing and going through some stats textbooks, I learned a bit more about the subject, but still not quite up to the right level needed to solve this question.

I went to StackExchange, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736137/find-the-probability-density-function-of-z-xy), and it seems to have a plausible answer. But why are the bounds on the integration plus/minus infinity? Would I have to change that in my case as I have defined bounds?

Comment: You technically don’t need to restrict the integral, if you treat $f_X(x)$ as zero for $x>a$ or $x<0,$ and likewise for $Y.$ And, indeed it is useful to do so, because it is easier to write the bounds for  $$\int f_X(t)f_Y(z-t)\,dt$$  Without defining $f_X,f_Y$ outside their “natural” domains, when $z$ is positive and small you’d have to write it as $$\int_{0}^z f_X(t)f_Y(z-t)\,dt$$ and when $z$ is close to $a+b$ the integral would be $$f_Z(z)=\int_{z-b}^a f_X(t)f_{Y}(z-t)\,dt$$ You kind of have to do the messy case work if you want to write $f_Z$ in a relatively close form.

Comment: You cannot find the density function of $X+Y$ if you do not know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, they are independent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If I take the definite integral over the real plane, I will end up with a diverging integral, as $f_x(t)$ and $f_y(t)$ are constants ($1/a$ or $1/b$), leaving the integral of $1$. So it seems I will have to do the second approach.

Comment: Your PDFs are constants _on their support_. If $x$ is outside their support, then both vanish. So the integrals are by no means divergent.

Comment: @Semiclassical So then the integrals evaluate to zero, as $f_x(t)$ and $f+y(t)$ are both zero at plus/minus infinity? That makes no sense either.

Comment: No. For convenience, take $a=b=1$. Then $f_X(x)f(y)=1$ if $x,y$ are both in $[0,1]$ and zero otherwise. Then for any $z$ there's a finite range of $t$ such that $f_X(t)f_Y(z-t)=1$ and zero otherwise. (This is just Thomas's point above.) For instance, when $z=1/2$ one needs $t$ and $1/2-t$ to both be between $0$ and $1$, so $0\leq t\leq 1/2$. Hence the integral is just $f_Z(1/2)=\int_0^{1/2} 1\,dt=1/2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical That makes more sense. So for me I need to integrate between 0 and $max(a, b)$? Just thinking a bit, $Z$ can never take on a value greater than the maximum of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That's not quite right either. The largest possible value for $Z$ is $a+b$. Moreover, to explain another point Thomas made above: If $z$ is closer to its maximum $a+b$ than its minimum $0$, then both $x$ and $y$ will have to be greater than their minimum values (0). (If $z$ is closer to the minimum, then both must be smaller than their max values.) So the two different ranges reflect two different cases. (Integrating over all $t$ hides this fact, which gives a tidy formula but isn't so helpful for computation.)

Comment: So can I do one integration from 0 to $z$, and then a second from $z-a$ to $b$? Then I get $z/ab$ for the first and $1/a - (z-a)/b$ for the second.

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm a bit confused. Would there need to be a third case here too?

Right now I'm assuming WLOG $a ≤ b$ (otherwise we flip them), and then I have two obvious cases: $0 ≤ z ≤ b$ and $b ≤ z ≤ a+b$. Then I can integrate the first from 0 to $z$ and the second from $z-a$ to $b$, like Thomas said. But do I need to consider the case $0 ≤ z ≤ a$ also? I have not seen anything like that from what I've found.